# Need to add a space between First and Last name

Tags: javascript

Can't seem to add spacing between first and last name. Modal displays as
[image: EXAMPLE]

```js
str = objclient.CommonWebClient(customerAdd, objapi.InsertCustomer, SessionHelper.token);

if (str != "-1") {
  BaseModelClass baseModel = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<BaseModelClass>(str);
  
  if (baseModel.status != 0 || baseModel.message == "Exists") {
    TempData["ModelData"] = "modalCompleteAddCustomer";
      
    if (baseModel.message == "Exists") {
      TempData["CustomerData"] = "Exists";
    } else {
      TempData["CustomerData"] = (Convert.ToString(customer.FirstName) + " ").Trim() + customer.LastName;
    }        
  }
}
```

Comment: just remove `Trim()`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
TempData["CustomerData"] = (Convert.ToString(customer.FirstName).Trim() + " ") + customer.LastName;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `trim()` method.

Should be this way instead;

```
 TempData["CustomerData"] = (Convert.ToString(customer.FirstName) + " ") + 
 customer.LastName;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `trim()` method removes whitespace OR Space from both ends.
Try updating the last lines with this code:

```js
TempData["CustomerData"] = (Convert.ToString(customer.FirstName)).Trim() +" "+ customer.LastName;
```

This is what I changed:

```js
(Convert.ToString(customer.FirstName)).Trim() +" "
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you just add an whitespace

```
  TempData["CustomerData"] = (Convert.ToString(customer.FirstName) + " ").Trim() + " " + customer.LastName;
```